# How to force java to accept the same type generic parameters

Tags: java

I found the following code snippet from The Java™ Tutorials Type Inference

```
static <T> T pick(T a1, T a2) { return a2; } 
Serializable s = pick("d", new ArrayList<String>());
```

So `a1` and `a2` can be different type here, how can I force them to be the same type? say only `pick("d", "e");` can be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
how can I force them to be the same type?
```

If T is very specific type like only `String`, then one simply can avoid generic. But you can restrict there scope, like -

```
static <T extends Number> T pick(T a1, T a2) { return a2; }
```

`pick(0, 1)`, As T is restricted to Number and sub classes. I've not draw the example of `<T extends String>` as `String` class is `final`.

Comment: Thank you for your answering but I can still call like this pick(1,1.0); Maybe java doesn't support this